# Sinatra output file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Hope it makes sense.

I am working with sinatra and haml and what i want is:

To output the file to the public directory as plain html for templating using.

I other words i do this in sinatra:

```
get '/hello/:name/:city' do
  "Hello world"
end
```

So... I want an HTML file created for example in the public directory with that same content.

Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Do you want this to be written when the request is made to a web site, or do you just want to use Haml for templating with a normal Ruby script? If the former, then you want a Sinatra caching library like [this](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-cache). If the latter, then you don't want to use Sinatra at all and you just want to use Haml and `File.open`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want something like [markaby/parkaby](http://www.rubyinside.com/parkaby-faster-html-generation-with-ruby-1965.html) or [rubified](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubified), am I right?